# List all currently connected users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to hide sheets that are not relevant to anyone who is logged in. There is a list of users on the top right of the screen next to the chat and comments functions.

Is it possible to get that information into script?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible using the standard Google Apps Script services.

It might be possible with the experimental Google Real Time API, but you would have to investigate and experiment with that to determine both if it is possible, and to how to access that API from Apps Script.  This wouldn't be a straight forward task.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's the first time I have heard of Google Real Time API. I shall check it out and see if it provides a solution. Thanks.